# Office Ribbon large and small images

Tags: excel, vba, office365, ribbon

Images in the office ribbon can be large (32x32) or small (16x16).  If they are specified as large, but the window is too narrow to fit them, then they are automatically made small.  By default, these are just a condensed version of the larger image.

There was an office design document (since disappeared) that suggested that one should properly design the small icons, and that they should not just be small versions of the big ones because condensing to 16x16 does not always work very well.  Very sensible.

But does one actually do it in the XML?  Elements like Button only seem to have one image attribute.  I would expect two, largeImage and smallImage (say).

Is this something that really needs horrible call backs?  In which case, how does one catch the event that the ribbon has decided to resize the image?  (Ribbon call backs are a mess with VBA for several reasons.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ribbon XML does not have an option to specify large and small icons as part of its defintion. If you use the `image` attribute then you can provide only one picture.

There's also no way to catch whether/when Office reduces the size of the Ribbon. You'd have to do some research, checking which window width triggers the resize, then you could use the `WindowResize` event of the Application object to invalidate the control(s), changing the picture (and possibly the control size).

In order to provide more than one icon you'd need to use the callback attribute `getImage` to tell the Ribbon which picture to use. This isn't as simple as passing the string value of a file stored in the Office document as the callback function expects an `IPictureDisp` object; the image would need to be stored outside the Office document, as a file.

The intricacies of using `getImage` are described in [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)), near the end of the article, but the code provided there is for the .NET Framework.

It's actually a bit easier to code using VBA since the `stdOle` library that provides `IPictureDisp` is an office library. You need to set a reference to the library - in the VBA Editor's Tools/References it's labelled as `OLE Automation`. Note that this does not work with the graphic png file format - the library is a bit old...

```
Public Sub GetIconImage(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef image)     
  Dim sPicPath As String
  Dim stdPic As StdPicture

  sPicPath = "C:\Users\[userName]\Pictures\test.jpg"  'Schweiz.png"
  Set stdPic = stdole.StdFunctions.LoadPicture(sPicPath)
  Set image = stdPic
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, as I feared.  They use different images in their own ribbons, recommend it in their style guide, yet do not support it.  Idiots.

Comment: Best to avoid callbacks into VBA.  They won't work if the debugger is active, producing nasty messages.  And dirty tricks are required to save the handle if there is ever a VBA error.  There are some sensible articles at https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win015.htm, but use a xl4 Application Named range to store it.

Comment: @Turntable Well, the debugger normally wouldn't be active "in production", so I'm not convinced that's a valid reason for not using callbacks. These days, I wouldn't use Named ranges to store things needed by code. Instead, I'd write them to a Custom XML Part...

Comment: There used to be a concept of End User Computing.  Where advanced Excel users could write simple code themselves, without dealing with horrendous deployment complexity.  It still happens with VBA, so weakening the debugger matters, even "in production" as other people are likely writing code.  One thing that is certain is that no end user will tackle the new JavaScript interfaces!

Comment: I might add that I have found developing ribbons with large icons quite difficult because they also should look reasonable when condensed, and the shrinking algorithm is not very smart.  But thanks for your confirmation that there is no easy way.

Comment: Apparently the article at https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/design/add-in-icons.md refers to allowing muli-sized icons for the new Web JavaScript stuff.  I suspect that traditional Excel is as dead as VBA as far as Microsoft is concerned.